# How to get a zig zag output in console using java for?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, infinite-loop

I am very new to coding and not very good at it :(

I've been struggling to do a project for my class for several hours now and I have scoured the internet with little use.

I need to make it appear on my console as if a ball is bouncing back and forth, the width of the ball bounce is set by the user.

So far, my output just produces an infinite left to right diagonal spanning the width chosen by the user.

My code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Midterm1_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        double yourNum;
        System.out.println("How many spaces wide would you like the ball to bounce?");
        yourNum= scan.nextDouble();
        String ballBounce = new String ("o")
        int count = 0;
        while (count < 50){
            System.out.println(ballBounce);
            String x = " ";
            for (int row = 1; row < yourNum; row++) {
                System.out.println(x+"o");
                x+= " ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get it to return right to left? My assumption is another for statement. But so far everything I've tried does not work.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is not necessarily the shortest one, it is meant to get the OP some ideas but without providing her/him with a straight answer. If the OP will copy the code as it is and doesn't adapt it, it should be obvious to the teacher the code is copied from somewhere. In case the OP understands it, it will be easy to clean and simplify the solution.

You have 2 methods below, take your pick **only after you read the code and understand it** (there is another one which I eliminated on purpose: this is an exercise of learning, so the obvious one is left as an exercise).

For the first method (`paintBallAt_1`), go read [PrintStream.printf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))

For the second method (`paintBallAt_2`), go read [String.substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))

```
public class Midterm1_1 {
    static private String ballBounce = "o";


    public static void paintBallAt_1(int x) {
       if(x==0) {
           System.out.println("o");
       }
       else {
           // will get your format strings as "%1$1c\n", "%1$2c\n", etc
           String formatString="%1$"+x+"c\n";
           System.out.printf(formatString, 'o');
       }
    }

    // 6x20=120 spaces at max. Limit or expand them how you see fit
    static public final String filler=
        "                    "+
        "                    "+
        "                    "+
        "                    "+
        "                    "+
        "                    "
    ;
    static public final int MAX_BOUNCE=filler.length();

    public static void paintBallAt_2(int x) {
       if(x>MAX_BOUNCE) {
         x=MAX_BOUNCE;
       }
       if(x<0) {
          x=0;
       }
       String bounceSpace=filler.substring(0, x);
       System.out.println(bounceSpace+"o");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        int yourNum;
        System.out.println("How many spaces wide would you like the ball to bounce?");
        yourNum= scan.nextInt();
        int count = 0;
        while (count < 50) {
            System.out.println(ballBounce);
            String x = " ";
            for (int row = 1; row < yourNum; row++) {
                System.out.println(x+"o");
                x+= " ";
            }

            // bounce it to the left
            for (int row = yourNum-1; row >= 0; row--) {
                switch(row % 2) {
                   case 0:
                        paintBallAt_1(row);
                        break;
                   default:
                        paintBallAt_2(row);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```